# SAS - distance of observation to the center of cluster

Tags: sas, output, distance, hierarchical-clustering

is there an easy way how to obtain for each observation its distance from the center of its corresponding center of cluster ?

My task is following:

1. I have a dataset with 42 000 observations, each with 8 variables.
2. I run the cluster procedure in SAS

   ```
   proc cluster data=WORK.stndstandardized_0000 method=average pseudo noeigen outtree=WORK.tree;
   id POL_NUMBER;
   var stnd_P_M200 stnd_P_M150 stnd_P_M100 stnd_P_M50 stnd_P_50 stnd_P_100  stnd_P_150 stnd_P_200;
   run;

   proc tree out=WORK.part nclusters=10;
   id POL_NUMBER;
   copy stnd_P_M200 stnd_P_M150 stnd_P_M100 stnd_P_M50 stnd_P_50 stnd_P_100 stnd_P_150 stnd_P_200;
   proc sort;
   by cluster;
   run;
   ```
3. I am supposed to analyze the individual clusters and pick up the observations most closed to the center of the cluster and most distant from the center of cluster

My output contains all the observations with the corresponding name of the cluster. But I would like to get more detailed information, for example the distance of the observation to the center of the cluster.

Is there any automatic way, how to get it ? I have already spent quite a lot of time reading manuals but I haven´t found any way. Thank you for any help.

Comment: With Center, you refer to Centroid, right?

Comment: @ Dirk  I would actually prefer obtaining some central observation (i.e. the most average observation from the set of observations in the cluster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a solution using FastClus**

PROC FASTCLUS does not return you a tree of clusters, just the one sollution with the number of clusters you specify. The time required by PROC FASTCLUS is roughly proportional to the number of observations. Further, to my knowledge, it gives the same clusers, but other output datasets;

**Creating the clusters** `mean=mean` specifies you want your cetroids in a dataset ´work.mean´ and `out=prelim` specifies you want your observations, including the cluster number and distance in a dataset ´work.prelim´;

```
title2 ’Preliminary Analysis by FASTCLUS’;
proc fastclus data=sashelp.iris summary maxc=10 maxiter=99 converge=0
    mean=mean out=prelim cluster=preclus;
    var petal: sepal:;
run;
```

**The rest is old school SAS programming** 
which you will probably adapt to your requirements;

```
proc sort data=mean;
    by preclus;
proc sort data=prelim;
    by preclus distance;

data closest farthest;

    format Species $22. Distance 5.2
        SepalLength 5.2 centroidSepalLength 5.2  
        SepalWidth  5.2 centroidSepalWidth  5.2   
        PetalLength 5.2 centroidPetalLength 5.2  
        PetalWidth  5.2 centroidPetalWidth  5.2   ;
    merge prelim
        mean (rename=(
            SepalLength=centroidSepalLength 
            SepalWidth=centroidSepalWidth  
            PetalLength=centroidPetalLength 
            PetalWidth=centroidPetalWidth ) drop=_:);
    by preclus;
    if first.preclus then output closest;
    if last.preclus then output farthest;
run;
```

Comment: I think you mean 'farthest'   ;-)